# Tapku calendar not showing events when selecting day in different month

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, calendar, tapku

I am new to Tapku but I think this might be a bug:

1. Say you are in May 2013. In the month grid you can see (grayed out) the last 3 days of April (28th, 29th and 30th) and the first day of June. As usually, you can also see "bullet marks" at the bottom of each day indicating events happening on that specific day. In my example you can see a mark on June 1st.
2. Now tap on June 1st. As expected, the calendar grid switches to June 2013 and marks as selected the day just tapped (June 1st). The problem is that now you should see the lists of events happening on June 1st but nothing is shown (even though the "mark" for that day still appears, as expected).

[image: may and june]

3. If (in a day of the current selected month grid) you tap a day with events, everything works just fine. In my example I tapped June 15th. You can see that now an event appears under the calendar grid.
4. Tap again on June 1st and now we can see the events happening on that day (Anna Haro's Birthday):

[image: june alone]

I've been searching in the code trying to find if it was my fault at some point but just couldn't find any clue..

Would appreciate your help. 
Thank you

UPDATED WITH CODE:

TapkuCalendarViewController.h

```
#import <TapkuLibrary/TKCalendarMonthTableViewController.h>

@interface TapkuCalendarViewController : TKCalendarMonthTableViewController
@end
```

TapkuCalendarViewController.m

```
#import "TapkuCalendarViewController.h"
#import "EventKitController.h"

@implementation TapkuCalendarViewController
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Today"
                                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(selectTodayDate)];
    [self.monthView selectDate:[NSDate date]];
}

- (void)selectTodayDate {
    [self.monthView selectDate:[NSDate date]];
}

#pragma mark MonthView Delegate & DataSource
- (NSArray*)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView marksFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate toDate:(NSDate *)lastDate {


    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                                   fromDate:startDate
                                                                     toDate:lastDate
                                                                    options:NSWrapCalendarComponents];
    NSInteger numberOfDays = components.day +1;

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfDays];

    NSDate *day = startDate;
    for (int x = 0; x<numberOfDays; x++) {

        if ([[EventKitController listOfEventkitEventsAtDay:day] count] != 0) [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
        else [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];

        if (x < numberOfDays-1) day = [day dateByAddingOneDay]; // private category method

    }
    assert([day isEqualToDate:lastDate]);

    return array;

}

- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)newDate {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark UITableView Delegate & DataSource
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSDate *dateSelected = self.monthView.dateSelected;
    if (dateSelected == nil) return 0;
    else return [[EventKitController listOfEventkitEventsAtDay:dateSelected] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *const CELL_ID = @"TapkuCalendarCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_ID];
    if (cell == nil) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CELL_ID];

    EKEvent *event = [[EventKitController listOfEventkitEventsAtDay:self.monthView.dateSelected] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", event.startDate, event.title];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = event.location;


    return cell;

}

@end
```

Comment: I would say that the tableview is not resized for june

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. I have tested with December, January, March... and the same behavior happens all the time. It also happens with month grids rendered in 5 lines (weeks) like January or May (instead of 6 like June)

Comment: Anyway: we are not able to tell, if it is a bug or not, as you are not showing your code. I'll vote for closure as not a real question.

Comment: if you'd used proper indentation it would be much easier to read.

Comment: I'm new to StackOverflow. I'm doing my best. Sorry..

Comment: that has nothing to do with stack overflow. that applies to any code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29388/discussion-between-ercolemtar-and-ikinci-viking)

Comment: to discuss about what? help us help you — by formatting code in a way that it is easy to understand. And indentation is very helpful to identify blocks of code easily.

Comment: you mean the tab-indentation of all the lines?
I had problems with the 4spaces for each code-formatted line and that's why is shown without specific indentation for IFs and so on...

Comment: I'll try to improve it..

Comment: if you use Xcode do following: mark all code, cut it and paste it back. that will fix any indentation. that past it into your question, mark it and hit the code button. not that difficult.

Comment: My fault.. I didn't know there was a "code button" (I was indenting each line by myself with the 4-space code). I think now is properly indented (as it always was in my Xcode project before copying to stack overflow editor). Thanks for this advise also.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem exists here:

```
- (void) _tileSelectedWithData:(NSArray*)ar{
```

inside of TKCalendarMonthView.m

Normally, when a month change does not occur, this method is called:

```
[self.delegate calendarMonthView:self didSelectDate:[self dateSelected]];
```

However, when a month change does occur, this method is not called and the relevant table view data is not updated.  Adding a call to this method fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bug.

`didSelectDate:` **is getting called as normal** during a month change but the Month View's selected date property gets cleared. So it does a reload the Table View but when it gets to

```
NSDate *dateSelected = self.monthView.dateSelected;
```

the `self.monthView.dateSelected` is `nil` resulting in your empty table.

**Solution:** I have resorted keeping track of the last selected date myself at the end of

```
 - (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)newDate
```

Then use this `lastSelectedDate` variable in table view data source methods. The table view gets and displays the correct data when selecting days that change the month (like your example).